Dynamic Formula for Largest Sum of Invoices Based on Fiscal Year
I currently am using the fomula:
=INDEX('Aggregate by Company'!$A:$A,MATCH(LARGE(UNIQUE('Aggregate by Company'!$G:$G),1),'Aggregate by Company'!$G:$G,0))
to pull through a list of the top ten organizations based on their total invoices sum. It is currently not dynamic and I need to shift the $G:$G reference when looking at another fiscal year.
Question
Is there a way to generate the array in: UNIQUE('Aggregate by Company'!$G:$G) based off of search criteria (i.e, will change based on a Fiscal Year Selection.
Reference File ('Aggregate by Company') Setup:
enter image description here
I have tried nesting different lookups; various cell position identifiers.
